# php Header location not letting me into admin area

Tags: php, authentication, header, login-script

I recently started learning PHP. I've been working on a basic login page. Everything works great locally, but when it's uploaded to ipage, it just reloads the login page. If I enter incorrect login info, it tells me that I entered something wrong.

Here's my code...

login.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require 'connect.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    $uid = strip_tags($uid);
    $pwd = strip_tags($pwd);

    $uid = stripcslashes($uid);
    $pwd = stripcslashes($pwd);

    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $uid);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $pwd);


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$uid' LIMIT 1";

    $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $db_password = $row['pwd'];
    $pwd = password_verify($pwd, $row['pwd']);

    if ($pwd == $db_password) {
        //$_SESSION['username'] = $uid;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header("Location: http://website.com/dashboard.php");
        exit;

    }else {
        echo 'You didn\'t enter the correct information';
    }
}


?>
```

dashboard.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require 'connect.inc.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

    header("Location: http://website.com/login.php");
    exit();
}



?>
```

any help would be appreciated very much...

Comment: I know I am going to regret this question but ... what is ipage?

Comment: It's a hosting service.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php said what?

Comment: Try `header("Location: dashboard.php");`

Comment: It's not advisable to escape passwords, especially when it comes to ones such as `123'\abc` being perfectly valid. In escaping those, it will rewrite it as `123\'\abc` in turn failing on `password_verify()`, given that `password_hash()` was used to store the hash with.

Comment: Your database does have the same data on both localhost and ipage right?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I've tried error reporting with no luck or errors. I've also tried taking out the http://... in the header. I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem of your code lies in here

```
if ($pwd == $db_password) {
    //$_SESSION['username'] = $uid;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    header("Location: http://website.com/dashboard.php");
    exit;

}else {
    echo 'You didn\'t enter the correct information';
}
```

`password_verify()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` and you are trying to check if it is equal to `$db_password`. As fas as I know this will not be true so even though the password you are typing in is correct, the page won't go anywhere because the `if` statement is not working properly.

---

So in your case, this is how I think you should have your code

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require 'connect.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    $uid = strip_tags($uid);
    //$pwd = strip_tags($pwd);

    $uid = stripcslashes($uid);
    //$pwd = stripcslashes($pwd);

    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $uid);
    //$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $pwd);


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$uid' LIMIT 1";

    $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $db_password = $row['pwd'];
    $pwd = password_verify($pwd, $db_password);

    if ( $pwd === TRUE ) {
        //$_SESSION['username'] = $uid;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header("Location: http://website.com/dashboard.php");
        exit;

    }else {
        echo 'You didn\'t enter the correct information';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. I've tried your edits. Unfortunately, the result was the same.

Comment: Hey all. Thank you very much for the reply. It ended up being a problem with my hosting service. I guess that's what I get for using a cheap host. Thanks for all the input!